# Fixing OverLap of "x" Axis values in a ScatterPlot - MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

[image: Scatter Plot]

Hi,
How can I increase the "x" axis spread (by the appropriate python code) of the scatter plot so that each region label (Europe, S.Asia etc. etc.) will not over lap with each other as shown.
Please advice.

Have been struggling with it for quite some while.
Thanks

Comment: `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` should rotate the labels slightly so that are still readable without overlapping.

Comment: @mdgrogan Thanks, that does help solve the problem. However, I still wanted to know for future reference, if there is a method/code that can help stretch the "x" axis, if there are for ex. more values in the "x" axis as compared to "y" axis. Thanks

Comment: You can rescale the figure using `plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))` before the rest of your `plt` functions, e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider rotating the labels with:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

or increase figure size using:

```
fig = plt.scatter(...)
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
```

Comment: `plt.scatter` does not return a figure instance, but a `PathCollection` instance. So the second method as you have written it will not work.